# how to force prestashop 1.4 trailing slash for upgrade to 1.6

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop

I have an old Prestashop 1.4 install and the pages do not have a trailing slash.
example: domain.com/category

I want to upgrade to a new version of Prestashop (1.6)
This version forces a trailing slash (example: domain.com/category/) for al the good reasons. The issue is that I don't want to loose any of my rankings in any of the search engines.

So what I would like to do is configure the .htaccess of my current 1.4 install so that the trailing slash will be forced and will be working because now it will result in a 404.

This is the .htaccess and I have no clue where to start even after reading several blogs about redirecting and such. Can anyone help me or give advice?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on


#Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+ /category.php?id_category=$1&noredirect=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /category.php?id_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /supplier.php?id_supplier=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?id_product=$3&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?id_product=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /category.php?id_category=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page-not-found$ /404.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^address$ /address.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^addresses$ /addresses.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authentication$ /authentication.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^best-sales$ /best-sales.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cart$ /cart.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /contact-form.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^discount$ /discount.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^guest-tracking$ /guest-tracking.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-history$ /history.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^identity$ /identity.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers$ /manufacturer.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^my-account$ /my-account.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^new-products$ /new-products.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order$ /order.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-follow$ /order-follow.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^quick-order$ /order-opc.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-slip$ /order-slip.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^password-recovery$ /password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^prices-drop$ /prices-drop.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search$ /search.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ /sitemap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^stores$ /stores.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^supplier$ /supplier.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?product_name_seo=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?product_name_seo=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^suplr/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /supplier.php?supplier_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mfg/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /manufacturer.php?manufacturer_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?cms_category_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?cms_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/. /category.php?category_name_seo=$1&amp;noredirect=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /category.php?category_name=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+/ /category.php?id_category=$1&noredirect=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/ /category.php?id_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /supplier.php?id_supplier=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /cms.php?id_cms=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /cms.php?id_cms_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?id_product=$3&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?id_product=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lang-([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /category.php?id_category=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page-not-found/$ /404.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^address/$ /address.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^addresses/$ /addresses.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authentication/$ /authentication.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^best-sales/$ /best-sales.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cart/$ /cart.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ /contact-form.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^discount/$ /discount.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^guest-tracking/$ /guest-tracking.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-history/$ /history.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^identity/$ /identity.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/$ /manufacturer.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^my-account/$ /my-account.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^new-products/$ /new-products.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order/$ /order.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-follow/$ /order-follow.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^quick-order/$ /order-opc.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^order-slip/$ /order-slip.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^password-recovery/$ /password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^prices-drop/$ /prices-drop.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search/$ /search.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/$ /sitemap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^stores/$ /stores.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^supplier/$ /supplier.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?product_name_seo=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html /product.php?product_name_seo=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^suplr/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /supplier.php?supplier_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mfg/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /manufacturer.php?manufacturer_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?cms_category_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?cms_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/./ /category.php?category_name_seo=$1&amp;noredirect=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /category.php?category_name=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Florian but this results in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS so it probably keeps looping with this change.

Comment: Could you maybe have another look? I still cannot get it to work. Thanks in advance.